# Does a ball thrown down exert less force on the ground when we walk?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Scenario A: You stand still and throw a ball vertically down. When the ball hits the ground it exerts a specific force on the ground.

Scenario B: While walking you throw a ball vertically down. When the ball hits the ground it exerts a specific force on the ground.

Is the force in both scenarios equal or is it less in scenario B (because the ball hits the ground at a lower angle)?

Comment: The mass is the same and velocity in the vertical direction is the same.  This sounds like homework.

Comment: And horizontal component remains unaltered.

Comment: @Paparazzi: So the angle at which the ball hits the ground (in the ground frame of reference) doesn't matter as long as the vertical velocity is the same? PS: It isn't homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vertical velocity is the same then the vertical force is the same.
Clearly the weight does not change.